How to stop rerouting due to onAuthStateChange() call for updateUser()
Ques
How to updateUser() without moving away from the registration screen if subscribed to onAuthStateChange() ?
I want to reroute when Auth User changes on login & logout, but I dont want to reroute when user object is updated for email etc.
Auth Flow
In my React Native Expo project, I have subscribed to onAuthStateChanged() API which sets an authUser state from AuthProvider.
Then the useEffect() in _layout.tsx gets triggered on authUser change, and routes according to the user's login/registration state.
App first logs in via Phone+OTP and then the registration process starts where user provides name & email id etc, and it get updated via updateUser() api.
Issue
TLDR;
updateUser() -> onAuthStateChanged() -> setAuthUser() -> userEffect() reroutes away from registration step.
While the user is on a registration step screen, updateUser() is called, which eventually triggers the onAuthStateChanged(). Its callback updates the authUser in the context, and the useEffect() of _layout.tsx reroutes to the start of the registration flow. This disrupts the original registration flow.
I suspect this is a common issue, and a valid solution must already exist. Can someone point me to it?
I am currently using Supabase auth, but I assume same issue must exist with Firebase Auth.
Show me the code
// AuthContext.ts
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
  const { subsAuthStateChange } = useAuthService();

  const onAuthStateChanged = async (authUser) => {
    setAuthUser(authUser);
    setInitialized(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = subsAuthStateChange(onAuthStateChanged);  // auth.onAuthStateChange()
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authUser,initialized}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// _layout.tsx
const InitialLayout = () => {
  const { authUser, initialized } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized) return;

    if (authUser) {
      if (authUser.isAnonymous) router.replace(ROUTE_SWITCH.signUpAnon);
      else if (!authUser.isRegistered) router.replace(ROUTE_SWITCH.signUp);
      else router.replace(ROUTE_SWITCH.home);
    } else {
      router.replace(ROUTE_SWITCH.login);
    }
  }, [authUser, initialized ]);
};


EDIT
As frank mentioned in comment, Firebase updateUser() wont trigger onAuthStateChange(), so my question is limited to Supabase Auth only.
I am looking for some way to pause/unpause the onAuthStateChange() callback that I can control easily.

I think the first thing is to define what you want your app to do in this case. It sounds like you're saying that this code doesn't do what you expect, but you're not saying what you expect.  Minimally, if you don't want to route away, then why do you have code that does so?  Please edit your post to be more clear what you're trying to accomplish.

@DougStevenson, I want to route away in situation A, B & C (login, logout, anonymous login) so the routing code is there. But I dont want to route away in situation D and E (user object is updated for some metadata), which is where i need help. I can try adding more if conditions in the useEffect to decide route or not, but that would make it too complex looking into each field of user object. I am looking for something to pause and unpause the useEffect trigger on authUser change. if (!initialized || paused) return;

This looks like a common problem: updating user object while being subscribed to onAuthStateChanged() for main auth flow change. How to update user object in the mid of some stack screen ?

I suggest editing the post to contain all this updated information about the problem instead of leaving it buried in comments, which people might miss.

Firebase's auth state change handler only fires when the auth state changes (so login and logout), not when other properties of the user profile change. So I wouldn't expect it to fire in situations D and E above. If that is not wha tyou observe, please edit your question to show this (for example, by logging the flow and showing us the updated code and its output, so that we're all looking at the same thing).

@DougStevenson, I have updated the question itself.

@FrankvanPuffelen, Thanks for the info, I have updated the question and limited it to Supabase only.
